# Ruby on Rails + Sql Server 2005

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, sql-server-2005, adapter, windows-server

This has been addressed some time ago, but I've not had any luck following the steps outlined or advice suggested. Here's my situation:

- I've installed SQL Server '05 and have another (non-Ruby) application utilizing it successfully.
- I've got Rails up and running successfully (but only for MySQL.)
- I've installed the Rails sqlserver adapter gem (as well as its dependencies.)
- I've downloaded ADO.rb (now only available on older builds of Ruby-DBI) and placed it into c:\ruby\lib\ruby\site_ruby\1.8\DBD\ADO\ADO.rb.
- I've configured database.yml to use the sqlserver adapter and pointed it towards my database with valid login information.

When I attempt to run a migration, I get the ugly 'Unable to load driver ADO (uninitialized constant DBI::DBD::ADO)' error.

Thanks immensely for any assistance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So just make sure if you're working on Windows or Mac to set up an ODBC connection. You must indicate this explicitly in your database configuration for Rails.

Comment: Hey, I realise this is seven years old, but is there any chance you can elaborate on this, especially with respect to Ubuntu (14.04)? I'm trying to get a legacy project (Rails 2.0.2) set up so I can maintain it, and I've been following a ***massive*** rabbit hole that has led me to the same error.